# How to interpret scipy.stats.probplot results?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, statistics

I wanted to use `scipy.stats.probplot()` to perform some gaussianity test on `mydata`.

```
from scipy import stats
_,fit=stats.probplot(mydata, dist=stats.norm,plot=ax)
goodness_fit="%.2f" %fit[2]
```

The documentation says:

> **Generates a probability plot** of sample data against the quantiles of a
> specified theoretical distribution (the normal distribution by
> default). probplot optionally calculates a best-fit line for the data
> and plots the results using Matplotlib or a given plot function.
> probplot generates a probability plot, **which should not be confused
> with a Q-Q or a P-P plot**. Statsmodels has more extensive functionality
> of this type, see statsmodels.api.ProbPlot.

But if google **probability plot**, it is a common name for P-P plot, while the documentation says not to confuse the two things.

Now I am confused, what is this function doing?

Comment: It's returning the sorted sample date, and the sorted empirical quantiles. There's a matplotlib extension that takes this even further: https://matplotlib.org/mpl-probscale/tutorial/closer_look_at_viz.html

Comment: why is this different from a qq-plot? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot

Comment: it's explained in the link i provided you. if there's any specific language that's unclear, let me know.

Comment: my point is more that there is no guarantee scipy and mpl implementation are doing the same

Comment: I'm telling you that they are. i use scipy in mpl-probscale

Comment: @PaulH If I understand the link properly, output of `stats.probplot(mydata, dist="norm", plot=plt)` is Q-Q plot (X-axis is quantiles, not probabilities).
Also [Wikipedia definition of P-P plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%E2%80%93P_plot) is different than in the link.

Comment: if you're plotting probabilities, it's a probability plot. if you're plotting quantiles, it's a Q-Q plot. mpl-probscale does both.

Comment: @PaulH but the question is about what `probplot()` plots, not mpl-probscale. For me it looks like Q-Q plot, but the docstring claims it is not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I looked since hours for an answer to this question, and this can be found in the Scipy/Statsmodel code comments.

In **Scipy**, comment at https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/abdab61d65dda1591f9d742230f0d1459fd7c0fa/scipy/stats/morestats.py#L523 says:

> `probplot` generates a probability plot, which should not be confused with
>       a Q-Q or a P-P plot.  Statsmodels has more extensive functionality of this
>       type, see `statsmodels.api.ProbPlot`.

So, now, let's look at **Statsmodels**, where comment at https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/66fc298c51dc323ce8ab8564b07b1b3797108dad/statsmodels/graphics/gofplots.py#L58 says:

> ppplot : Probability-Probability plot
>              Compares the sample and theoretical probabilities (percentiles).
>
> qqplot : Quantile-Quantile plot
>              Compares the sample and theoretical quantiles
>
> probplot : Probability plot
>                Same as a Q-Q plot, however probabilities are shown in the scale of
>                the theoretical distribution (x-axis) and the y-axis contains
>                unscaled quantiles of the sample data.

**So, difference between QQ plot and Probability plot, in these modules, is related to the scales.**

Answer (score 8):

The theoretical probability of an event occurring is an "expected" probability based upon knowledge of the situation. It is the number of favorable outcomes to the number of possible outcomes.

When you gather data from observations during an experiment, you will be calculating an empirical (or experimental) probability.

**Example**: You tossed a coin and you got a head.

- Experimental Probability(head)=1
- Theoretical Probability(head)=0.5

For simplicity, see the below diagram which shows probability of getting particular Bill amount. p and q plot are shown.
[image]

**ppplot** (Probability-Probability plot)

- Compares the sample and theoretical probabilities (percentiles).

**qqplot** (Quantile-Quantile plot)

- Compares the sample and theoretical quantiles

**probplot** (Probability plot)

- Same as a Q-Q plot, however probabilities are shown in the scale of the theoretical distribution (x-axis) and the y-axis contains unscaled quantiles of the sample data.

Difference between ppplot,qqplot and probplot are related to the scales. Both show sample and theoretical values on x and y  axis.

[image]

**Percentile plots**

- Percentile plots are the simplest plots. You simply plot the data against their plotting positions. The plotting positions are shown on a linear scale, but the data can be scaled as appropriate.

**Quantile plots**

- Quantile plots are similar to probabilty plots. The main differences is that plotting positions are converted into quantiles or ZZ-scores based on a probability distribution.

The default distribution is the standard-normal distribution. You’ll notice that the shape of the data is straighter on the Q-Q plot than the P-P plot. This is due to the transformation that takes place when converting the plotting positions to a distribution’s quantiles.

**Best-fit lines**

- Adding a best-fit line to a probability plot can provide insight as to whether or not a dataset can be characterized by a distribution.

[image]

In statistics and probability quantiles are cut points dividing the range of a probability distribution into continuous intervals with equal probabilities, or dividing the observations in a sample in the same way.

Probability density of a normal distribution, with quartiles shown. The area below the red curve is the same in the intervals (−∞,Q1), (Q1,Q2), (Q2,Q3), and (Q3,+∞).

In statistics, a Q–Q (quantile-quantile) plot is a probability plot, which is a graphical method for comparing two probability distributions by plotting their quantiles against each other.

If the two distributions being compared are similar, the points in the Q–Q plot will approximately lie on the line y = x. If the distributions are linearly related, the points in the Q–Q plot will approximately lie on a line, but not necessarily on the line y = x.

A Q–Q plot is used to compare the shapes of distributions, providing a graphical view of how properties such as location, scale, and skewness are similar or different in the two distributions.

A P–P plot plots two cumulative distribution functions (cdfs) against each other: It is a probability plot for assessing how closely two data sets agree, which plots the two cumulative distribution functions against each other. P-P plots are vastly used to evaluate the skewness of a distribution.